# Make command line stay open when running a bat file

Tags: ant, batch-file

I want my batch file to stay open after processing is complete.

Here is my code:

```
set CLASSPATH=C:\XSLTANT\examples\word_transform\apache-ant-1.8.1\bin
set PATH=%CLASSPATH%
ant >> transform.log
echo "See transform.log for results"
pause
```

It closes instantly after it runs the `ant` build. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the line:

```
ant >> transform.log
```

to

```
CALL ant >> transform.log
```

This is required when running one batch file from another.

Comment: Thanks that works. Is there another param I can use that will make the ant output log on the screen and in the log file?